# Groovy write out the list to a file

Tags: groovy

```
File lstFile = new File(lstFileName).withWriter{out->
            archivedFiles.each {out.println it.name}
}
```

archivedFiles is a List objects .. I am getting an error that says:

```
Cannot cast object with class 'java.util.ArrayList' to class 'java.io.File'.
```

I am only interested in writing out file names contained in the list to the NEWLY created file

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That's beacuse the `withWriter` block is returning the last thing in the block by default (which is the `archivedFiles` list)

To do what you're trying to do, you'd need to do:

```
File lstFile = new File(lstFileName)
lstFile.withWriter{ out ->
  archivedFiles.each {out.println it.name}
}
```

or this should work too:

```
File lstFile = new File( lstFileName ).with { file ->
  file.withWriter{ out ->
    archivedFiles.each {out.println it.name}
  }
  file
}
```